# How can I get out of Windows IoT reboot loop?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

So I have Windows IoT running on a RPi2, I deployed an app ( which was working fine in the debugger) and set it to run headless at startup. It seems to be throwing and unhandled exception on boot which is causing the Windows to then reboot. Is there anyway to prevent the app from starting and get out of the reboot loop to allow deployment of a new version? Seems Windows IoT is a bit unstable if it has to reboot because one startup app fails.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows 10 IoT Core App to connect to the Admin Webpage of your page and change the default start app. Ok, you must be fast during the boot process to get to change it ;) HTH

Comment: You really have to be quick, but I made it. Thanks for the advice.